# Error opening '/home/ec2-user/app/tukaweb/Passengerfile.json' for reading: Permission denied (errno=13)

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, ruby-on-rails-5, passenger, nginx-config

Getting the below errors in the errorlog file of the install nginx using passenger on aws server version

> 2019/11/27 12:53:57 [alert] 11012#0: *8 Error opening
>   '/home/ec2-user/app/tukaweb/Passengerfile.json' for reading:
>   Permission denied (errno=13); This error means that the Nginx worker
>   process (PID 11012, running as UID 99) does not have permission to
>   access this file. Please read this page to learn how to fix this
>   problem:
>   https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/admin/nginx/troubleshooting/?a=upon-accessing-the-web-app-nginx-reports-a-permission-denied-error;
>   Extra info, client: 180.151.2.195, server:
>   ec2-52-10-247-34.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com, request: "GET
>   /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host:
>   "ec2-52-10-247-34.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com", referrer:
>   "http://ec2-52-10-247-34.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/"

passenger memory status:

> [ec2-user@ip-172-31-8-180 logs]$ passenger-memory-stats Version: 6.0.4
>   Date   : 2019-11-27 13:17:32 +0000
>   ------------- Apache processes -------------
>   *** WARNING: The Apache executable cannot be found. Please set the APXS2 environment variable to your 'apxs2' executable's filename, or
>   set the HTTPD environment variable to your 'httpd' or 'apache2'
>   executable's filename.
>
> ---------- Nginx processes ---------- PID    PPID   VMSize   Private  Name
>   ------------------------------------- 11004  1      55.0 MB  ?        nginx: master process /opt/nginx/sbin/nginx 11012  11004  55.4 MB  ?
>   nginx: worker process
>
> #### Processes: 2
>
> #### Total private dirty RSS: 0.00 MB (?)
>
> ----- Passenger processes ------ PID    VMSize     Private  Name
>   -------------------------------- 10983  388.7 MB   ?        Passenger watchdog 10986  1830.1 MB  ?        Passenger core
>
> #### Processes: 2
>
> #### Total private dirty RSS: 0.00 MB (?)
>
> *** WARNING: Please run this tool with rvmsudo. Otherwise the private dirty RSS (a reliable metric for real memory usage) of processes
>   cannot be determined.

Not able to resolve this issue for Rails installation with passneger and nginx.

```
[ec2-user@ip ]$ ruby -v
ruby 2.4.0p0 (2016-12-24 revision 57164) [x86_64-linux]
[ec2-user@ip-]$ rvm -v
rvm 1.29.9 (latest) by Michal Papis, Piotr Kuczynski, Wayne E. Seguin [https://rvm.io]
 rails -v Rails 5.2.3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Become root user go to the home directory  and execute the below command and restart the server.

```
chmod g+x,o+x ec2-user
```

ec2-user is you user home directory